# 'No audio output device is installed' in Windows 10 after Linux Mint 18.1 boot

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, sound-card

Once I boot up from a Linux Mint 18.1 USB I get a 'No audio output device is installed' in Windows 10.  The sound will work fine in Linux Mint but after I reboot and go to Windows 10, I'll get the error again and have no sound.

The only temporary solution I found for now was to re-install the BIOS drivers from the Alienware website.  That gets rid of the error and I get sound again but once I reboot in Linux Mint, the error will come back again.

I just purchased 2 brand new laptops (Alienware 13 R3) and an Asus ROG GL553VD and the same problem occurs on both systems.  It seems that just even a linux boot from a USB messes up something on my system and after that Windows 10 no longer recognizes my sound card.